# Bypass golang http handler

Tags: http, go

Let's say I have code like this

```
handler := middleware1.New(
    middleware2.New(
        middleware3.New(
            middleware4.New(
                NewHandler()
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
```

where handler has tons of middleware.

Now I want to create custom endpoint, which will skip all the middleware, so nothing what's inside `serveHTTP()` functions is executed:

```
http.HandleFunc("/testing", func(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    r *http.Request,
) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "it works!")
    return
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)
```

But this doesn't work and `/testing` is never reached. Ideally, I don't want to modify `handler` at all, is that possible?

Comment: `http.HandleFunc` applies to the `DefaultServeMux`, not your `handler`.  Do you want to add `handler` to a `ServeMux` or do you want to add `/testing` to your `handler`?

Comment: @JimB Adding handler to ServeMux seems to be better solution, right? Because adding `/testing` to handler won't skip middleware, am I right?

Comment: Yes, if `handler` doesn't do any muxing before the middleware, then you need to do it separately -- a ServeMux (or any muxer/router package) can do that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [`http.ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) to route requests to the correct handler:

```
m := http.NewServeMux()
m.HandleFunc("/testing", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "it works!")
    return
})
m.Handle("/", handler)

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", m)
```

Using the `http.HandleFunc` and `http.Handle` functions will accomplish the same result using the `http.DefaultServerMux`, in which case you would leave the handler argument to `ListenAndServe` as `nil`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this, ListenAndServe handler is usually nil.

```
http.Handle("/", handler)

http.HandleFunc("/testing", func(
    w http.ResponseWriter,
    r *http.Request,
) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "it works!")
    return
})
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```